# MySQL Update a column value with the rowid of the group

Tags: mysql

I have a table of images, which are associated with a particular group (vehID) and I need to create their order for each group.

This is for an initial image entries position for a field I forgot to design in.

I have been playing with `@row`, but not getting very far.

```
set @row= 0;
select @row:=@row+1 as row, vehID,imgID from images group by vehID;
```

This gives me the rowID but does not reset for each group

Each vehID has 1 to n entries and I wish to calculate that value and update that rows' entry with the calculated value.

I can not work out how to reset @row to 0 on a change of vehID. Probably some sub-select.

If I can get Select to work any advice on how code the UPDATE if not obvious would be appreciated

```
Update images set imgPosition = Calculated Value where imgID = current imgID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to declare another variable that holds the previous vehID. then using an IF statement you can compare the vehID with the previous one and set the row number accordingly. and then you set the previous vehID variable to be the vehID of the current row.

please note that I changed "group by" to "order by". this is for two reasons:

1- to list all rows

2- to make sure that rows from same id are following each other. otherwise comparing with previous value will not be correct.

and last, make sure you compare the previous vehID value and decide what the rownum is before you reset the previous variable to hold the value of the current line.

```
set @previous_vehID= 0;
set @row= 0;
select if(@previous_vehID=vehID, @row:=@row+1, @row:=1) as row,@previous_vehID:=vehID, vehID,imgID from images order by vehID
```

**EDIT:**

I just missed the update part. you can try cross table update for that:

```
set @previous_vehID= 0;
set @row= 0;
update images a, (
    select if(@previous_vehID=vehID, @row:=@row+1, @row:=1) as row,@previous_vehID:=vehID, vehID,imgID from images order by vehID ) aa
set a.imgPosition = aa.row where a.vehID=aa.vehID and a.imgID=aa.imgID
```

the above makes the select and the update in a single statement/query. if not working, insert the results into a temporary table and use them to make an update in a separate statement.

Comment: Outstanding - I would not have worked that out EVER.  Until yesterday I did not know you could use variables and IF statements.  Now all my images are sequenced. I hope this is useful to many more people. Thank you very much.